# phpUnit: mysql log doesn't show up, using Symfony 1

Tags: mysql, logging, symfony1, yaml

i'm using Symfony 1.1 with the following settings.yml:

```
test:
  .settings:
    error_reporting:        <?php echo (E_ALL | E_STRICT)."\n" ?>
    web_debug:              true
    cache:                  true
    no_script_name:         false
    etag:                   false
    logging_enabled:        true
```

but when i execute phpunit to run my test, nothing is logged into log/backend_test.log but one line which is:

> Sep 26 11:27:47 symfony [info] {sfPatternRouting} Match route "homepage" (/) for / with parameters array (  'module' => 'default', 
>    'action' => 'index',)

i do execute an sql, but it's now showing up.

my logging.yml looks like this:

```
test:
  enabled:  on
  level:    debug
  rotate:   off
  period:   7
  history:  10
  purge:    on
```

Comment: Can we see what is done in your `default/index` action ?